# String to PublicKey using Diffie-Hellman algorithm

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

I have a Public key string (128 bytes byte to hex processed) given by my client. I need to generate shared key using the private key and Public key given by client. I'm getting below exception while converting the String to Public key. I tried **decoding/encoding** the bytes, no improvement. I have the following code.

// This is a sample key.

```
private static final String PUB_KEY = "0DC1B7102DE3F6785A284ABFCA1822A6B59C947B5F2FAAE" + "672D8EE29C3D801BC153777CD3AF5478FD25C234C50BBABF8CD5215A8F1CB19B0B4A24FD5E9" + "412264646E2A06FCB5929FFBE196A1BD58B9927424C3B3D0388FDDA15FD1FF1C3E7600A629E" + 
"B3F0B38B85CCCE03D44CF8D53B2E4E5EFD54E991CE92E55B10FCCD79F04";

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {   
    PublicKey key = getKey(h2b(PUB_KEY));
}

private static PublicKey getKey(final byte[] pubKey) throws Exception {
    final KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");  
    final X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKey);
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec); // THROWS EXCEPTION
}

private static byte[] h2b(String hex) {
    if ((hex.length() & 0x01) == 0x01)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < bytes.length; ++idx) {
        int hi = Character.digit((int) hex.charAt(idx * 2), 16);
        int lo = Character.digit((int) hex.charAt(idx * 2 + 1), 16);
        if ((hi < 0) || (lo < 0))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        bytes[idx] = (byte) ((hi << 4) | lo);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Throws follwoing excetpion. Any help to solve this?

**Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DHKeyFactory.java:87)**

Comment: How can a radix-16 digit ever be negative?

Answer (score 0):

The `X509EncodedKeySpec` is expected to contain an array of bytes with the ASN.1 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure.

The `PUB_KEY` in your example is probably the raw key value (`y` in the terms of `javax.crypto.spec.DHPublicKeySpec`) which is not enough to create the keyspec.

You should ask your client eother for the proper public key in the ASN.1 form to be used as input for `X509EncodedKeySpec` (this is preferable) or for `p` and `g` parameters required for `DHPublicKeySpec`.

Comment: Thank you for the Responses. I have p and g values generated from pem. I have generated my key pair as well. Client's code is in C. I have mailed client to get public key in ASN.1 form. Is there anything I can do with p, g and keypair i generated?

Answer (score 0):

1. Follow 3 steps convert String to DH,DSA publickey or privatekey

### Generate Publickey

```
KeyPair pair = keyPair.generateDHKeyPair();// this will generate public private key
PublicKey publicKey=pair.getPublic();
```

2:convert publickey to publicKey.getEncoded return byte[].

```
byte[] byte_pubkey = public_key.getEncoded();
System.out.println("\nBYTE KEY::: " + byte_pubkey);
```

3://converting byte to String

```
String pukkey64 = "";
        //byte[] pukkey64 = new byte[0];
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
            pukkey64 = encoder.encodeToString(byte_pubkey);
            Log.e("pukkey64", new String(pukkey64));
        } 

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // GenpubKeyFromString(pair2.getPublic().toString());
            try {
                GenpubKeyFromString(pukkey64);
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This  Function Generate the publickey or private key whatever you need

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    void GenpubKeyFromString(String pubKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] publicKeyBytes=decoder.decode(pubKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
        PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes));
        Log.e("publicKey String", publicKey.toString());
        
    }
```

// convert string to privatekey

```
public static PrivateKey GetPrivateKeyFromString(String priKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(priKey, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
        return privateKey;
    }
```