# string to publicKey

Tags: java, string, public-key

there. I'm implementing Diffie Hellman key exchange protocol between a java application and a php server.I have some issue when i get the key from the php server, the key is a String format and i want to convert it to a PublicKey to perform the protocol.
The code is the next:

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] byteKey =publicKey.getBytes();
    X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
    KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
    PublicKey pubKey = keyFact.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
    DHPublicKey dhPublicKey;
    return pubKey;
}
```

when i run this function i've got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DHKeyFactory.java:87)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
at main2.getPublicKey(main2.java:47)
at main2.main(main2.java:108)
```

The key is a big integer type like:"2730833911517276610828829348409530515930034154987099616280024338836450623403836102419905982575105923164305996145622906355021487887788144551871008554848191"
How can i correct this problem?
Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't directly have an answer, but basically the same question has been asked before, and the only answer seems to imply that perhaps your publicKey string is not the correct ASN.1 structure:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676620/string-to-publickey-using-diffie-hellman-algorithm

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't find it with the search button! I have generator and prime, but the problem remain, I can't convert them to publicKey.

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved the problem thank's to user3062946. Here's the code:

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(BigInteger publicKey, BigInteger p, BigInteger g) throws Exception {
    DHPublicKeySpec dhspec=new DHPublicKeySpec(publicKey,p,g);
    KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
    PublicKey pubKey = keyFact.generatePublic(dhspec);

    return pubKey;
}
```